# servlet logged users

Tags: jsp, servlets

In jsp servlet application, is there any way to send messages to all logged users or only to some specific users?

My requirement is, I have one login page. After login it has to calculate how many users have logged in and based on that, I need to send message to all logged users. Apart from this I need to send message to only some specific logged users. Is it possible to achieve this functionality without using any web socket functionality?

Comment: What is the message you want to send? A letter to email or a message in browser on HTTP protocol?

Comment: It is simple text message. Like what we are doing in Chat. For example a new user has logged in, then it has to be informed the already users that this particular user logged. Also some kind of text messages to specified users not all users.

Comment: You can show each user necessary unique message depending on value of  its properties or other conditions. In the same way as you display him other information. What's exactly problem?

Comment: But what ever the information which we pass to only one client right? That information how do we pass to all? How can we set the property? I am new to this concept, that is the reason I am asking deeply.